# Nature of levitation bahvior in superconductor magnetic pinning

Tags: magnetic-fields, superconductivity, levitation

I am aware of superconductor levitation (eg. https://youtu.be/Vxror-fnOL4) and have a vague knowledge that it has something to do with superconductor pinning of the magnetic field, but I have no intuition for the nature of the resulting levitation/locking behavior. I would like to ask a series of questions based on a shared geometry:

Imagine a long (infinite) current carrying wire generating a magnetic field around it. For specificity say the wire runs along the $z$ axis and we'll work in cylindrical coordinates with $r$ being the distance from the $z$ axis and $\theta$ being the angle around the $z$ axis. The magnetic field lines are circular about the $z$ axis (weakening as $1/r$ as you go out). We'll ignore gravity and any external forces.

Now let's take a small puck of a type II superconductor and put it off to the side of the wire. In what directions would it be able to freely move?

[image: https://imgur.com/a/j7Wxu7x]

I assume the puck is not allowed to move in $r$ as the magnetic field changes in that direction. I assume it *is* allowed to move in $\theta$. The magnetic field is constant in $\theta$, and I can imagine the puck smoothly gliding along the circular magnetic field lines almost as if they were fine penetrating threads. Can the puck freely move in the $z$ direction? The field is constant in $z$, but the puck will be moving *through* rather than *along* magnetic field lines.